# XSLT normalize-space not working

Tags: xslt

Here is my input xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<content>
  <body>
        <p>This      is a Test</p>
        <p>
          Toronto,           ON - Text added here.
        </p>
  </body>
</content>
```

and here is my style sheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
  extension-element-prefixes="str">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" />


  <!-- Root / document element-->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When i apply this transformation using the ASP.NET XslCompiledTransform's transform method and view the result in the browser, I still can see the spaces and the normalize-space does not seem to be working.

Can any one please let me know what i am doing wrong

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you Phil and Stuart...tried both the suggestions but it did not help

Comment: Just to confirm, you want to strip all Html out of the output as well?

Comment: No for now i want to just strip out the spaces, i dont care about the other tags. One strange thing was when i pasted the xml on which i am testing into the http://xsltransform.net/ site, it showed the . character where i was expecting spaces, It looks like the xml being generated by this other program is inputting some character that looks like a space but is really not one.

Comment: I will need to investigate what that character is. Thanks a lot for all your replies!!!

Answer (score 2):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(text()[2])]/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided source XML document**:

```
<content>
  <body>
        <p>This      is a Test</p>
        <p>
          Toronto,           ON - Text added here.
        </p>
  </body>
</content>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<content><body><p>This is a Test</p>
        <p>Toronto, ON - Text added here.</p>
  </body>
</content>
```

**Update**:

In case the problem is caused by a space-like character(s), here is a solution that will replace the unwanted (up to 40 per text node) characters with spaces and then normalize-space() would do its work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vAllowed" select=
   "concat('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXUZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
           '0123456789.,-')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vSpaces" select="'                                        '"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[not(text()[2])]/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select=
    "normalize-space(translate(., translate(.,$vAllowed,''), $vSpaces))"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When the transformation is applied on this source XML document**:

````
<content>
  <body>
        <p>This \\\     is a  ~~~ Test</p>
        <p>
          Toronto,    ```       ON - Text added here.
        </p>
  </body>
````

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<content>
  <body>
        <p>This is a Test</p>
        <p>Toronto, ON - Text added here.</p>
  </body>
</content>
```

Comment: Were you able to reproduce the problem?

Comment: The code *isn't* working. The OP, when asked if he wanted to stip off the markup, answered: `"No for now i want to just strip out the spaces"`   But his code only produces the text nodes. As for the whitespace -- even if the original source XML document is viewed in a browser (unchanged), each whitespace span should be displayed as a single space by the browser. Therefore, he must have some intermediate transformation that converts each whitespace character to a non-breaking white space (or something else -- for the dot that he mentions). He could issue `view source` and provide the input

Comment: @michael.hor257k, See the updated answer. The transformation now replaces any unwanted characters with spaces and then `normalize-space()` does its work.

Answer (score 1):

Dimitre's answer is of course great, but there is a typo. In $vAllowed he's missing a capital "Y."

Also for my own purposes, I needed a single quote or apostrophe to be an allowed character. I added it to the variable like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="vAllowed" select=
    "concat('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
    '0123456789.,-', '&apos;&apos;')"/>
```